# Highcharts - get width of each slice of a column chart

Tags: highcharts

I have the highcharts,column chart, wherein I need to draw a notification bar on each of the months.

Please find image, I need to set the yellow bar under each month.
Please can anyone help me get the each width of the slice.

[image]

Thanks for ur help
Regards
Ruth

Comment: You will probably need to use renderer. Should the line be visible on hover - like a short crosshair under categories? or at all times? Second question: should all categories have yellow underline? This would lead to a single yellow line under all categories, right?

Comment: If at all times and under all categories, then use [renderer](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Renderer.path) like in this simple example: http://jsfiddle.net/59v8z18f/